# How to configure primefaces Gmap to show a specific country

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, localization

I am using primefaces Gmap in my application, and I want the map to show only Turkey country and it's regions. Does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508688/1659451) answer, you can follow sth. like this:

```
<p:gmap id="gmap" widgetVar="myMap"></p:gmap>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gmap = myMap.getMap();
    var table_id = 420419; //can be exchanged wit another table
var FT_Query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM "+ table_id +" WHERE 'name_0' NOT EQUAL TO 'TURKEY'";
var FT_Options =
    {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: FT_Query
    };
var layer =  new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(table_id, FT_Options);
layer.setMap(gmap);
</script>
```

Another way mentioned [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm);

> If you want to limit the range of zoom levels that the user is allowed
>   to use on your map, you can overwrite the .getMinimumResolution() and
>   .getMaximumResolution() methods of all the map types.

[Demo](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_range.htm).

Comment: well sorry for that I am not deep at kml stuff, if you checked all links I am going to delete my answer.

Comment: thanks for your effort just keep them so that somebody can make benefit of them