# KML invert country border

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-api-2

I need invert KML file with Poland country. 
I need white overlay on other countries, only Poland should be visible.
http://cv.bluewolf.pl/kml-map/
I have a problem with converting borders, and place white overlay on the rest of the world. Only one country (Poland) should be visible.

I tried use KML winding reversal tool from geocodezip but i can't find any tutorial or documentation.
I tried Mask-KML-polygons from github to transform KML file but this don't work.

Somone could tell me what can I use to get this effect on map?
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_NetherlandsInverted.html

Comment: Where is the file that you tried to invert?

Comment: I download file from http://www.gadm.org/country > Poland > Goole Earth .kmz and uinzip this to kml file.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811223/can-i-show-a-single-country-masked-out-in-googlemaps

Comment: What problem did you have with the file from [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/)?  Where is that file?

Comment: Yes, I read this. But I don't understand how can I make KML like this exemple. I think I should change something on <outerBoundaryIs> and <innerBoundaryIs> tag. But i can't find any tutorial or solution.

Comment: My map which i try invert: http://cv.bluewolf.pl/kml-map/

Answer (score 3):

According to the [winding reversal tool](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/POL_adm0.kml), all the polygons in POL_adm0.kml wind in the negative direction.

```
name Poland
outer -0.000029027214395682677
outer -0.00011758931589156418
outer -0.00004442846750407625
outer -0.0011201874443713677
outer -0.00001914283006954065
outer -0.0002913248119966738
outer -0.000060512058212225384
outer -0.0055139375892849785
outer -0.000024386593850067584
outer -0.000016341876744263573
outer -0.00001358358349534683
outer -0.00022344898320625362
outer -0.010447627167081919
outer -0.0026826606504073425
outer -0.07199650440122696
outer -0.00004660667070766067
outer -0.007425361581113066
outer -81.8301486672533
```

All  you need to do is add an outerBoundaryIs that winds in the opposite direction and change all the existing outerBoundaryIs tags to innerBoundaryIs tags.  Here is an `<outerBoundaryIs>` that winds in the correct direction:

```
<outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
180,85 90,85 0,85 -90,85 -180,85 -180,0 -180,-85 -90,-85 0,-85 90,-85 180,-85 180,0 180,85 
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
```

[Updated KMZ file (displayed on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?lat=52.166772&lng=19.621582&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/pol_adm0_inverted.kmz)

[image: Screenshot of Poland inverted polygon]

**Note:** It works with native Google Maps Polygons (in geoxml3), but not with [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer).